# Is there a way to prevent infinite updates in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

If I make a mistake in a Firestore cloud update function on a document that updates itself, is there some way to detect and terminate the loop?

I'm afraid of running up huge firestore charges by a dumb mistake in writing cloud functions.

Comment: I'm surprised there's no official boiler plate to guard against this!

Comment: There is usually a way to detect this, but it depends on your specific code. To give you some idea, today I was writing a Cloud Function that triggered itself intentionally 2 times, but then had to stop after that. There's no way for the system itself to detect such conditions, so it's up to your code to do it. If you need help figuring out how to exit your code correctly, post the [minimal, complete/standalone code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

**You will have to detect that case in your function code.**  There's no automatic detection.  Specifically, your code will need to be able to recognize the situation where an update that triggers the function was a result of a prior update from the function itself.  Sometimes this involves checking a flag in the document that indicates it was already processed, or finding some other way to see if the work was already done.  If it was, the function should simply return without updating the document again.

There is a video that discusses the same problem with Realtime Database.  It's the exact same issue, just with a different database.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bdm7QNwSHOg

Comment: Ok thanks.  It seems like Google should provide some setting that stops this sort of recursive update of the same set of records after n updates so you don't go broke because you didn't catch the bug.

Comment: It's actually not really "recursive", and not even really a loop. It's a cause/effect relationship.  Cloud Functions was designed to be stateless, which is the only way that the system can scale effectively. In cases like this, you have to provide your own state.  If you disagree, please feel free to file an issue with Firebase support, but I don't think anything will happen (trust me, as I used to be on the Cloud Functions team).

Comment: If you're concerned about billing, you can always set up billing alerts to let you know when your total spend is too high for your budget.  https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the billiing alerts, but I wonder about what sort of magnitude of charges you can run up over a short period of time if you have an update chain which is essentially circular. It doesn't seem that hard a mistake to make, like, if I have an a set of update triggers where B updates C and C updates D, and then a few days later I write a trigger where D updates B.  If I don't check my email till the next morning, how I wonder how big a bill I might end up with?  $1, $10? $1000?

Comment: Contact Firebase support if you have questions about how to deal with billing issues. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support